# Django: Cannot assign string: class must be a class instance

Tags: python, django

This is my first Django's page. I know that it exists many reported problems like this but I haven't found the correct answer.

I have a database that I can show perfectly, and I wannna allow to users to add new entries.

models.py

```
class Server(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=13)


class Usuario(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    servidor = models.ForeignKey(Server, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    correo = models.EmailField()
    fpago = models.DateField('Fecha de pago', auto_now_add=True)
```

And views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login/')
def suscripciones(request):

    obj_usuarios = Usuario.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        servidor = request.POST.get('servidor')
        correo = request.POST.get('correo')

        consulta = Usuario(servidor=servidor, correo=correo)

        consulta.save()

    return render(request, 'APP/suscripciones.html',
                  {'obj_usuarios': obj_usuarios})
```

The model works when without the request.method and consulta but with this code I get this error:

Cannot assign "(string with the server's name)": "Usuario.servidor" must be a "Server" instance.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parse a request `servidor = request.POST.get('servidor')` you receive a
string "servidor". For sending it to `Usuario`, try to retrieve `Server` instance like that:

```py
# ...
servidor = request.POST.get('servidor')
servidor = Server.objects.filter(name=servidor).first()
correo = request.POST.get('correo')

consulta = Usuario(servidor=servidor, correo=correo)
```